# How do I move all Google Sheets rows of data into Google Docs template fields

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach, google-docs

I'm currently have a Google Sheet *(Pushed to a website via PHP)* with all my clients beer data. I'd like to take that data and copy it into a Google Doc Template for easy printing. In my example I can move the first row of data from the Sheet into the Doc but all the other rows from the sheet do not copy over.

I could use some help with the forEach statement, I'm thinking I need to parse the array and iterate through it in a different way than I'm currently attempting. *(First time using Apps Script)*

Here is what I've currently coded up.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Print Menu');
  menu.addItem('Create New Print Menu', 'createNewMenu')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewMenu() {
  //Google Doc Template ID and Where to Save the New File
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1xzlvVOSW_LsgOrm2N2o1-FKYzfqp_2EAbhqrLTn53yk');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('11HU0TvSPMMXUZaK5gTgg8jvofxTTt02j');

  //Get all spreadsheet sheets and add values as 2D arrays.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Draft List');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Create date for new filename.
  const dateData = new Date();
  const curr_date = dateData.getDate();
  const curr_month = dateData.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  const curr_year = dateData.getFullYear();
  const theDate = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
  const newFileName = theDate + ' - Bar Print Menu';

  //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(newFileName, destinationFolder)

  //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())

  //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
  const body = doc.getBody();

  rows.forEach(function(rowData) {
    //In these lines, we replace our template replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet rows.
    body.replaceText('{{onTapName}}', rowData[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{onTapDescription}}', rowData[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{onTapPrice}}', rowData[2]);

    //Logger.log(rowData);
  });

    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

This code will create a copy of the template file, copy the first row of data from Google Sheets and paste it into the template in the {{onTapName}}, {{onTapDescription}} & {{onTapPrice}} areas but the other rows from the Google Sheet do not copy over.

[- Screenshot of Google Sheet, Google Doc Template and Result after running above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Nt2.jpg)

If I uncomment out the "Logger.log(rowData);" line, I can see the code is going through each line of the data from the Google Sheet.

[- Screenshot of Execution Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpkCB.png)

How do I modify this forEach area to copy through each line of code into the template? I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `How do I modify this forEach area to copy through each line of code into the template?` and your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. Do you want to create each Google Document from the template document for every row? Or, do you want to create only one Google Document including all rows? From your question, I couldn't understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Comment: I would suggest creating an app that appends new paragraphs instead of replacing text.  Once the text is replaced there are no further placeholders for the remaining text.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry if I wasn't being clear.  Yes I would like to create a single Google Document which includes all the rows.

Comment: @Cooper Being new to Apps Script I wasn't aware that was an option.  Another possibility I was thinking of was creating multiple variables and removing the ones which aren't being used but I'm not sure if that's possible with Apps Script.

The benefit of pushing to Google Drive is the users can update the Google Sheet which can pull to the website via php and then if I can pus the Sheet data to a Google Doc they can format and print with a press of a button by just updating the Google Sheet.

Comment: Try reading the documentation to learn about all of the methods for each class.   They constantly add new methods all of the time so we all have to reread the documentation all of the time